# How to Get USB Descriptor of an USB CCID Card Reader (Only by using CCID Device Name)

Tags: usb, wmi, smartcard-reader

When I connect multiple USB CCID card reader devices to my computer (all of them are same model) I can get the names of CCID devices like these (I can get these names by PCSC library) :

-MicroChip Card Reader 1

-MicroChip Card Reader 2

-MicroChip Card Reader 3

Now, what i want to find/match USB descriptors of these USB CCID devices. I want to do this by only using CCID Device names. Later i'll get serialNumbers of these devices from their USB Descriptors.

```
-MicroChip Card Reader 1    -->         9812398127983
-MicroChip Card Reader 2    -->        1298371829212
-MicroChip Card Reader 3    -->         494182874r822
```

I researched this subject a lot, but I couldn't come to any conclusion.

Under WMI I can find these CCID device names under Win32_PNPEntity PnPDeviceID : SWD\SCDEVICEENUM\

Under WMI I can find serial numbers under Win32_PNPEntity PnpDeviceID : USB\

I can also find serial numbers under Win32_UsbDevice.

But I can't match serial numbers with CCID card reader names.

How can I do this?